# Meaning of function name @ suffix

Tags: linux, function

can you explain what is the meaning of the `@@` and `@` suffixes in the function names?, Does it means that the function is statically linked with the suffix value?
I'm not sure I have GLIBC 2.4 dynamic library on my system (or maybe I do have?).. I do have higher version of glibc..

**Example:**

```
00000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.4 (3)
00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memcmp@@GLIBC_2.4
```

Thanks.